# Multiple MCP41010 Digital Potentiometers Work From One CS Signal

Tags: audio, control, sound, digital-potentiometer

tell me please, for example, I control for example any parameter of the sound path of the guitar pedal with the help of MCP41010 and I need to make a dual potentiometer of two single-channel chips for the right and left channel, probably it does not make sense to send the same CS signal from different digital pins arduino and I’m can combine two CS inputs MCP41010.

Comment: Extend the length of the packet, and clock a leading group of bits into a SIPO register, the outputs which set the CS pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the digital pots are intended to be operated identically then you can use common communication lines and a common chip select line providing that the communication is purely from master to slave devices. Given that the MCP41010 only has clock and data inputs this isn't going to be a problem.

Of course you could always consider a dual device like the MCP42010: -

[image]

It has a common CS line and can be daisy-chained with other MCP42xxx devices thus saving on seperate SCK and SI lines for all other instances of digipots in your circuit.